# disable autocomplete / autofill for an input field

Tags: html

I have this input field which shows me a list of google address suggestions:

```
<input type="text" id="customerAddress" name="customerAddress" placeholder="Adresse (Vorschlag übernehmen)" autocomplete="off">
```

I would like to prevent the autocomplete / autofill function of any browser.
For this I tried "autocomplete=off", but it doesn't work. The autofill wasn't disabled:

[image]

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You will find an explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#disabling_autocompletion) (after the code blocks).

You can either try to change the `name` attribute of your fields or set the `autocomplete` attribute to `"off"` on the `form` tag instead.

Comment: i tried this before. but without success

Comment: @Ghost108 You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30976223/16688813).

Comment: I had this problems only with edge and chrome. I tried `autocomplete=off`, `autocomplete=new-password` and `autocomplete=chrome-off`. Nothing works ! :(

Comment: @Ghost108 if it didn't work and not either `<form autocomplete="off">` or changing the `name` attribute of your `input`, I'm affraid I have no other solution.